# How can I save Image file to SQL database with .NET Core and EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, file-upload, iformfile

There is a problem here, the title and description are saving correctly in the SQL database, but it is sending the image file as null. I made some attempts in this way, but I did not get the result I wanted.

How can I print this?

My class:

```
public class Workplace
{
        [Key]
        [Column("WorkplaceId")]
        public int WorkplaceId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Column("WorkplaceThumbnailImage")]
        public byte[]? WorkpaceThumbnailImage { get; set; }

        [Column("WorkplaceTitle")]
        public string? WorkplaceTite { get; set; }

        [Column("WorkplaceExpanation")]
        public string? WorkplaceExplanation { get; set; }
}
```

Controller post method:

```
WorkplaceManager workplaceManager = new WorkplaceManager(new EfWorkplaceRepository());

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Workplace p)
{
    Workplace workPlace = new Workplace();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
    {
        p.WorkplaceTite = file.FileName;
        file.CopyTo(memoryStream);

        p.WorkpaceThumbnailImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    p.WorkpaceThumbnailImage = p.WorkpaceThumbnailImage;
    p.WorkplaceTite = p.WorkplaceTite;
    p.WorkplaceExplanation = p.WorkplaceExplanation;

    workplaceManager.AddWorkplace(p);

    _logger.LogWarning("Success");

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                    
}
```

HTML:

```
@model EntityLayer.Concrete.Workplace;
@using (Html.BeginForm("Workplaces", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart / form - data"}))
{
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="inputText">Add</label>
                        <input type="File" class="form-control" id="file" name="file1" multiple="multiple"
                               asp-controller="Home" @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WorkpaceThumbnailImage) method="post"/>
                    </div>
}
```

Comment: We need to see the markup code for the View or Page that calls the controller method.

Comment: @Steve I updated the question, I think this is the piece of code you mentioned

Comment: i know this is not the solution you are looking for.. but the foreach loop that you have written will overwrite the property values and will always have the last file data irrespective of the number of files you receive.

Comment: To have a Html.BeginForm know that it should post a file you need to add enctype = ‘multipart/form-data’ attribute

Comment: @Steve I applied enctype = "multipart/form-data" change in BeginForm, but it is certain that I did something wrong or missing, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Use IFormFile instead of byte  to get the file details

Comment: @KiranJoshi If I'm not mistaken, your method will work with IFormFile, but will only save the file path to the database. This is not exactly what I want, convert "Image" to bytes and save it in database. So I want to keep the file in a database, not in a folder.

Comment: Did you debug what is `Request.Form.Files` whether it is empty and what does it contain?

Comment: @Ergis I debugged but didn't come across anything

Comment: remove the spaces from this: "multipart / form - data" inside the form tag

Comment: @riffnl unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Do you actually receive a file on the backend? If not - there is nothing to push to the database.

Comment: @riffnl After turning the computer on and off I did the edit you suggested and the edits by other contributors and it's working now. After turning the computer on and off I did the edit you suggested and the edits by other contributors and it's working now.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My class:

```
public class Workplace
    {
            [Key]
            [Column("WorkplaceId")]
            public int WorkplaceId { get; set; }
    
            [NotMapped]
            [Column("WorkplaceThumbnailImage")]
            public byte[]? WorkpaceThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    
            [Column("WorkplaceTitle")]
            public string? WorkplaceTite { get; set; }
    
            [Column("WorkplaceExpanation")]
            public string? WorkplaceExplanation { get; set; }
    }
```

Controler post method:

```
WorkplaceManager workplaceManager = new WorkplaceManager(new EfWorkplaceRepository());
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Workplace p)
    {

        Workplace workPlace = new Workplace();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        foreach (IFormFile file in Request.Form.Files)
        {
            workPlace.WorkplaceTite = file.Name;
            file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

            p.WorkplaceThumbnailImage = memoryStream.ToArray();


            workPlace.WorkplaceThumbnailImage = workPlace.WorkplaceThumbnailImage;
            p.WorkplaceTite = p.WorkplaceTite;
            p.WorkplaceExplanation = p.WorkplaceExplanation;
        }
        workplaceManager.AddWorkplace(p);
                
        _logger.LogWarning("Success");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Html:

```
@model EntityLayer.Concrete.Workplace;
@using (Html.BeginForm("Workplaces", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div class="card text-white rounded-3 sm-3">
                        <button class="btn card text-white rounded-3" type="submit" asp-area="" id="create" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Hairdresser" style="background-color: #5B2480;">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
}
```

This is how I edited the codes with your suggestions. It works flawlessly. Thanks to those who contributed. I realized that the problem is caused by missing resources and spaces in "BeginForm".

Comment: you should have given the correct answer to @Ergis (marked as correct answer) with a possible comment about the incorrect BeginForm tag

Answer (score 0):

...you are using [[NotMapped]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=net-6.0) on the `WorkpaceThumbnailImage` property, which exludes it from database mapping.
Try removing it.

---

**Edit**
Try this other way:

```
public class Workplace
{
    [Key]
    [Column("WorkplaceId")]
    public int WorkplaceId { get; set; }

    [Column("WorkplaceThumbnailImage")]
    public byte[]? WorkpaceThumbnailImage { get {
        if(this.MyFile is null) 
            return null;
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        this.MyFile.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    } }

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile MyFile { get; set; }

    [Column("WorkplaceTitle")]
    public string? WorkplaceTite { get; set; }

    [Column("WorkplaceExpanation")]
    public string? WorkplaceExplanation { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
WorkplaceManager workplaceManager = new WorkplaceManager(new EfWorkplaceRepository());

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromForm] Workplace p)
{
    workplaceManager.AddWorkplace(p);

    _logger.LogWarning("Success");

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                    
}
```

View:
(Renamed the *id* and *name* attributes to *MyFile* because it should match the property name of the class)

```
@model EntityLayer.Concrete.Workplace;
@using (Html.BeginForm("Workplaces", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="MyFile">Add</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="MyFile" name="MyFile" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the fix, I removed the `[NotMapped]` attribute from the property

Comment: sorry, the problem persists. I missed these lines while debugging.  `p.WorkpaceThumbnailImage = memoryStream.ToArray(); p.WorkpaceThumbnailImage = p.WorkpaceThumbnailImage;`  These lines are returning blank.

Comment: You select file(s) and `Request.Form.Files` is still empty? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes that's what i wanted to say

Comment: Also, can you confirm, what database are you using (SQL or MySQL), and what is the type of the column of `WorkpaceThumbnailImage` in db?

Comment: Azure Data Studio SQL database using, `WorkpaceThumbnailImage`
 data table column type VarBinary(Max)

Comment: I tried your solution you created above but nothing changed

Comment: Do you get the entire model (`Workplace p`) as *null*, or just the file property? If the entire model is null, try adding `public IActionResult  Index([FromForm] Workplace p)` (added `[FromForm]`)

Comment: Wait a minute. Does it even hit the `Index` action? Now that I see, you are hitting the WRONG endpoint. Change `Html.BeginForm("Workplaces", "Home"...` to `Html.BeginForm("Workplaces", "Index"...`

Comment: `WorkpaceThumbnailImage` column sends blank. Other than that I fixed the `@BeginForm` but couldn't make any progress